# Переделываю AJAX запрос на ванильном js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Переделал этот код на jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: data
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  //done
});
```

Вот, как я это сделал на ванильном js:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

Но почему-то это не работает. Данные получаю на php через `$_POST['imgBase64']`

Во втором варианте не знаю, где указывать *imgBase64*(название переменной)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором варианте, в функцию send нужно передать тело POST-запроса. А именно - строку, содержащую данные в виде "param1=1&param2=2&param3=3".

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send('imgBase64=223');
```

Так ваш код будет работать.

Для подробного ознакомления на русском: [https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#отослать-данные-send](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-send)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все работает